# NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger

Tags: java, maven, logging, intellij-idea, log4j

I have used log4j logger in my java project and have the following in my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I have added `log4j.properties` inside a directory named "resources" which I have added as a source in intelliJ project structure.

When I build the project, it builds successfully. But when I try to run the `jar` file by running `java -jar myproject.jar`, it gives the following error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at org.wso2.confvalidator.ConfigValidator.<clinit>(ConfigValidator.java:40)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.log4j.Logger
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 1 more
```

Comment: Make sure to add the log4j jar (and I guess a bunch of other deps) to runtime classpath. I.e. -cp java option

Comment: I think you have multiple implementations of log4j in the classpath. I faced similar type of issue earlier. So please check it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are simply running your jar without the dependent jars. you need to add all the dependencies in your class path using the `-cp` command.

Another alternative is to use the `maven-shade-plugin` to create a "Fat" jar that contains the dependent java classes in the same jar. This makes running the jars using command line fairly simple. To use it, simply add the below snippet to your pom plugins section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
        <filters>
            <filter>
                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </filter>
        </filters>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                        <mainClass><ENTER_YOUR_MAINCLASS_HERE></mainClass>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>..</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </transformer>

                    <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                        <resource>META-INF/cxf/bus-extensions.txt</resource>
                    </transformer>

                </transformers>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Note: Please replace the main class of your jar appropriately at `<ENTER_YOUR_MAINCLASS_HERE>`

If you really do think there is an issue of same dependency with different versions being included multiple times, then you should use the

```
mvn dependency:tree
```

command to get the details of which libraries are being duplicated and then remove one of the versions from your dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Please try after **cleaning** your **maven repository**, sometimes it picks multiple versions of same jars.

Comment: I built using `dependency:purge-local-repository clean install` and then tried but the error is still there.

Comment: Please delete your maven repositories folder (if not whole then delete log4j folder only), command arguments does not work properly sometimes

Answer (score -1):

This is log4j version 2 dependency. Please try with this.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Then I get an error when building. `[ERROR] /home/sachithra/myproject/src/main/java/org/confvalidator/utils/XSDValidator.java:[20,24] package org.apache.log4j does not exist`